# How to get index of a list in array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list `a=[1,2,3,4]`, and an array `arr=np.array([[1,1,1,1],[1,2,3,4],[2,2,2,2])`. I want to compare `a` and `arr` to get the index of `a` in `arr`. How can I do that? I wish to get the output in integer (in this case is 1) because I need the index to proceed with other processes. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `arr.index(a)` should work fine.

Comment: `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'` this is what I get

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the index is to convert the numpy array to a python nested list and just use the index method() on the converted list

(By the way you are missing a closing "]" in your declaration of `arr`)

```
import numpy as np
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr=np.array([[1,1,1,1],[1,2,3,4],[2,2,2,2]])
lst = arr.tolist()
idx = lst.index(a)
```